# CSS "select" text spacing

Tags: css

I've the following issue: there is `<select>` option in my website, and it have 3 different logic data in one `<option>` which needs to be separated like this:

[image: example]
I was thinking about word-spacing, but as you can see there is some spaces in last data, so it will not work. `:after` and `:before` will be not good either.  And as I know there is no way to insert `<div>` or `<span>` inside `<option>`. I was wondering is there any other ways to implement this, because currently I have only bad solution with `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Can we see some code? and which "some spaces"

Comment: Which code do you want to see? It's just standart structure with <select><option>text here</option></select>. "Some spaces" - look at the "999 999 999 999" there is space between "999" and "999"

Comment: Yes. Like this "<option>123456789231&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBYR&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp999 999 999 999</option>" (yes, nbsp is just awful)

Comment: @Dazvolt: Please add the **relevant** HTML markup to the Question along-side the **relevant** CSS you currently have that does not do what you want. Including a jsFiddle (or similar) demonstrating the issue also helps. Without the exact markup and (if relevant) current CSS a lot of guessing and drip-feeding of information in comments might be needed.

Comment: Something like letter-spacing:-2px; can help you but would need a lot of work to make it look like what you want. Code would be nice. Please share a Fiddle. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to present `option` elements in a tabular manner, as it seems, then the clumsy way of using no-break spaces *and* a monospace font seems to be the only way.

Consider using a different approach, such as a set of radio buttons with associated labels and other texts. Then you can use a `table` element.

Answer (score 0):

I did a few changes to a library called **[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)** ... I think it's just what you need.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qucog/3/edit)**

This is the usage in JS:

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
  width: '250px',
  html: function(option){      
    return $(option).data('html');
  }
});
```